# Feeding a list of prospective objects into a class to be instantiated

Tags: python, pandas, class, instance

I can't seem to figure out what I think is supposed to be a simple operation, to instantiate some arbitrary list (or other container, may change over time) of a class I made.
Play Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['helen', 'peanut', 3],['helen', 'butter', 7],['agnes', 'tuna', 5]], columns=['registered_to', 'cat_name', 'sale_price'])

cat_owners = df.registered_to.unique()

class CatOwner():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self.spent_on_cats = df.loc[df.registered_to==name]['sale_price'].sum()

for owner in cat_owners:
    owner = CatOwner(owner) # I know this doesn't work.
```

`cat_owners = [CatOwner(name) for name in cat_owners] #this gets me close` (thank you for the suggestion @Tim Roberts), but not yet there.
helen.spent_on_cats #desired output = 10, instead error
cat_owners.helen.spent_on_cats #if I had to do it this way that'd be fine but this also doesn't work (first way preferred), error

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension shown in your question will give you a list (obviously) of references to CatOwner objects.

You do confuse matters by assigning the comprehension to a variable used within the comprehension.

Perhaps this will help as it's not entirely clear what your ultimate objective is:

```
import pandas as pd

class CatOwner():
    def __init__(self, name, df):
        self.name = name
        self.spent_on_cats = df.loc[df.registered_to == name]['sale_price'].sum()

df = pd.DataFrame([['helen', 'peanut', 3],
                ['helen', 'butter', 7],
                ['agnes', 'tuna', 5]],
                columns=['registered_to', 'cat_name', 'sale_price'])

for catowner in [CatOwner(name, df) for name in df.registered_to.unique()]:
    print(f'{catowner.name} spent {catowner.spent_on_cats} on cats')
```

Note how a reference to your dataframe is passed as an argument to the class constructor. Although *df* is available within the scope of your original code, as you restructure your program you could easily find that it's suddenly out-of-scope and your program will break. Better to do it this way IMO

Comment: Ultimate objective... Truth be told I am trying to take my org's 25 year old excel book into the next generation. The same person has been there this whole time. They're willing to learn, but, the pressure is on to connect a significant network of various excel books, with some aid from, SQL. The objects i'm trying to create here are the center of it all. They could easily have several hundred attributes and methods/functions.